# Phalcon: specific column on joined PHQL

Tags: phalcon

The below PHQL generates a complex resultset like it should:

```
$phql = "SELECT User.*, ProductUser.* "
      . "FROM ProductUser "
      . "INNER JOIN User "
      . "WHERE ProductUser.product_id = 5";
```

Replacing *ProductUser.** with an existing column like *ProductUser.id* causes an error:

> MESSAGE: The index does not exist in the row 
>   FILE: phalcon/mvc/model/row.zep 
>   LINE: 67

This is version 2.0.6. Is this a bug or am I making a mistake somewhere? According to the [documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html#joins) it should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake (expecting the row to always be an object).
I hope this helps someone because looping complex resultsets is not in the documentation.

```
$result = $this->modelsManager->createQuery($phql)->execute();

if ($result instanceof \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Complex) {
    foreach ($result as $rows) {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            if (is_object($row)) {
                $modelData = $row->toArray());
            // this is what I needed
            } else {
                $id = $row;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably have models for tables ProductUser and User, why not to use `queryBuilder` or internal Phalcons' model relation declarations?

Comment: @yergo Yes, queryBuilder will give the same result. I wish I could use model relations but I don't know how to get the "SELECT User.*, ProductUser.id" part in there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're missing the [`ON` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause) in your query.

Anyways, it's easier and more error prone to use [Phalcon's query builder](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html#creating-queries-using-the-query-builder) for querying:

```
<?php

// modelManager is avaiable in the default DI
$queryBuilder = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder();
$queryBuilder->from(["product" => 'Path\To\ProductUser']);

// Inner join params are: the model class path, the condition for the 'ON' clause, and optionally an alias for the table
$queryBuilder->innerJoin('Path\To\User', "product.user_id = user.id", "user");

$queryBuilder->columns([
    "product.*",
    "user.*"
]);

$queryBuilder->where("product.id = 5");

// You can use this line to debug what was generated
// $generatedQuery = $queryBuilder->getPhql();
// var_dump($generatedQuery);

// Finish the query building
$query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();

// Execute it and get the results
$result = $query->execute();

// Now use var_dump to see how the result was fetched
var_dump($result);
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The error was coming from phalcon/mvc/model/row. By the way you don't always need an ON clause in PHQL but yes I ended up using it to get the correct result.

Comment: @galki When you don't need to use the `ON`clause?! When there FK's set in the table schema or something?

Comment: yup just take a look at the link in my question. I commented out all my model relations and it still gave me a broken result :/

Comment: @galki that's odd, anyways, why aren't you using the build-in methods for getting related records?! When you set a relationship you can provide an alias then simply use something like `$product->user`. Not sure what is your context but it might be easier and faster since the `user` property will be fetched only when you need it.

Comment: this is a tricky case with a dynamically generated ManyToMany query with models A B and C and in addition to getting relation C I need to get B.id.